# Defining inline style in React, SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

While trying to disable scrolling on the page setting `style='overflow-y: auto;'`:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div style={{overflow-y: auto}}>
        <div>{this.props.title}</div>
        <div>{this.props.children}</div>
      </div>
    );
}
```

**Webpack** is giving an error:

[image]

What could I do here? If we can not set `overflow-y` for some reason, then how could we disable scrolling of a web page in `React` app (I am also using `React-Bootstrap`)

Comment: need to quote it? Or camel case?

Comment: `overflowY` . . .

Comment: Awesome, works fine, thank you!

Comment: Please select the answer below. (I don't get points, it's just so we know it's been answered.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The style attributes should be in camel case according to the [documentation](https://react-cn.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html).

So anywhere we delimit the words with hyphen (-) in normal css we should use change them to camel case when we use it inside a react style object.

For example.

```
overflow-y -> overflowY
overflow-x -> overflowX
background-image -> backgroundImage
```

We insert the styles as an object.

so the css properties will be attributes of an javascript object.

**hyphen(-) is an illegal character when defining javascript object attributes or variable names**. That's why it should be used in **camel-Case**.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, use overflowY.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `<div style={{overflow-y: auto}}>`

You have to convert it into camelCase like `<div style={{overflowY: auto}}>`

For details you can Check react official document 
Here https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style