# How to add style inline in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

How to add style inline in React. I tried this approach but it fails. I am not getting the difference

```
<ul style = {{padding-left: '21px'}}>
<u style={{ text - underline -position: 'under' }}>
```

but this runs properly:

```
<ul style={{ color: '#007acc' , textDecoration: 'none' }}>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Defining inline style in React, SyntaxError: Unexpected token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48001015/defining-inline-style-in-react-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **React** the `style` attribute requires a **JavaScript** object. In your second case you are passing similarly like the following - like making a variable what you pass to `style`:

```
const stlye = { color: '#007acc', textDecoration: 'none' };

<ul style={style}>
```

See from the documentation for the [`style`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style) attribute:

> The style attribute accepts a JavaScript object with camelCased properties rather than a CSS string. This is consistent with the DOM style JavaScript property, is more efficient, and prevents XSS security holes.

So for your requested style can be applied as the following as *camelCased*:

```
<ul style={ { textUnderlinePosition: 'under', paddingLeft: '21px' } }>
```

I hope this clarifies!

Comment: hi @norbitrial how can i use  these two (text - underline -position: 'under') and (padding-left: '21px')

Comment: @Akhi21 Just extended my answer with those properties.

Answer (score 0):

Well bcs that's how you add styles in Javascript, remember, what you are writing of html tags is not html itself, it is Javascript that gets compiled to html, so that you have to always remove - and capitalize the next letter.